# Send all currently buffer output to client and navigate to other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to send all currently buffer output (which is Some Random Codes to excel sheet) to client and navigate to other page.

I am facing problems like

1. If I use Response.End() the page stops executing and Response.Redirect doesn't execute.
2. If I use Response.Flush() the page sends the buffer output but at time of redirection **I am getting exception "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."**

My code is like this:

```
// this code sends some codes to excel.
ExportToExcel(Codes);
Response.End(); // what should i use
Response.Redirect("Coupons.aspx");
```

The ExportToExcel mehtod:

```
public void ExportToExcel(List<string> codes)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        string.Format("attachment; filename={0}_CODES.xls", DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d")));
    // Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=""MyFile.pdf""");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

    List<string> codeList = codes;

    string str = "COUPON CODES";

    Response.Write(str);
    str = "\t";
    Response.Write("\n");
    Response.Write("\n");
    foreach (string code in codeList)
    {
        Response.Write(code);
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
}
```

This is my 1st time asking question here.. Any reply and suggestions will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A normal HTTP request has one answer - you've sent the response with the Excel sheet already. What you are trying is to send another ( a second response, which is not defined ). You should consider  taking another approach - open the link for the Excel document in a new window ( that closes because it's a download ) and on click navigate the main window to the next page. For example

Comment: You cannot send 2 responses to a client at the same time. Response.End() sends HTTP 200 OK with the excel file contents and throws a ThreadAbortException to the caller. Response.Redirect on the other hand sends HTTP 302. You cannot expect a browser to get the excel file response and continue to listen for more responses. Change your ExportToExcel to a HttpHandler, redirect from this page and at the redirected page, navigate to the HttpHandler in a new tab or in a new window

Comment: i know i can't send 2 responses for single request. but i was wondering is there any way to send those 2 response as a single response.. i am just curious. and sorry for my bad English ,

Comment: There is no way. Your English is OK by the way.

Comment: @OguzOzgul thank you :) i will do it by another way